# Python 2.7: Tkinter/ttk Linked ComboBoxes

Tags: combobox, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

I've made a simple GUI using a GUI editor called PAGE. It contains two Tkinter.ttk combo boxes. My first combo box gets its values as column names from a connected sqlite database table. When I choose a column name from first combo box, second combo box should update its values automatically related to first values.

BTW, my codes below work properly in this current condition. If I choose a value from first combo box, It'll print the values to interactive shell. But these values should insert into second combo box. Does anyone know how can I figure it out?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Here are my GUI codes:

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as db
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

def getdata():
    global colnames
    conn = db.connect("blabla.sqlite")
    cur = conn.execute("select * from states")
    col = cur.description
    colnames = [abu[0] for abu in col]
initcombo = getdata()

def vp_start_gui():

    global val, w, root
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Linked Comboboxes')
    root.geometry('301x230+556+208')
    set_Tk_var()
    w = New_Toplevel_1 (root)
    init()
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_New_Toplevel_1 (root):

    global w, w_win
    if w: 
        return
    w = Toplevel (root)
    w.title('New_Toplevel_1')
    w.geometry('301x230+556+208')
    set_Tk_var()
    w_win = New_Toplevel_1 (w)
    init()
    return w_win

def destroy_New_Toplevel_1 ():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None


def set_Tk_var():

    global combobox
    combobox = StringVar()


def init():
    pass


class New_Toplevel_1:
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        style = ttk.Style()
        theme = style.theme_use()
        default = style.lookup(theme, 'background')
        master.configure(background=default)


        def choose1(event=None):
            conn2 = db.connect("blabla.sqlite")
            cur2 = conn2.execute("select %s from states" % self.TCombobox1.get())
            results = cur2.fetchall()
            for row in results:
                print row


        self.TCombobox1 = ttk.Combobox (master, state='readonly')
        self.TCombobox1.place(relx=0.03,rely=0.13,relheight=0.09,relwidth=0.48)
        self.TCombobox1["values"] = colnames
        self.TCombobox1.set("Choose one...")
        self.TCombobox1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", choose1)

        self.TCombobox2 = ttk.Combobox (master, state='readonly')
        self.TCombobox2.place(relx=0.03,rely=0.33,relheight=0.09,relwidth=0.48)


        self.TLabel1 = ttk.Label (master)
        self.TLabel1.place(relx=0.03,rely=0.83,height=19,width=28)
        self.TLabel1.configure(relief="flat")
        self.TLabel1.configure(text='''Info:''')

        self.TButton1 = ttk.Button (master)
        self.TButton1.place(relx=0.63,rely=0.22,height=25,width=76)
        self.TButton1.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TButton1.configure(text='''Run''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the 'results' as the value of the 'values' config of the second combobox.

```
def choose1(event=None):
        conn2 = db.connect("blabla.sqlite")
        cur2 = conn2.execute("select %s from states" % self.TCombobox1.get())
        results = cur2.fetchall()
        self.TCombobox2['values'] = results
        for row in results:
            print row
```